# "[, ...args]" in Socket.io docs

Tags: javascript, socket.io

[`socket.emit(eventName[, ...args][, ack])`](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack)

Hello everyone. I just had a simple question. When I'm reading through documentation. The thing I find a little confusing is what certain things mean. So I know if you have something like `[, ack]`. That means it's optional but what about `[, ...args]`. I'm guessing it means it's optional too and you can specify more than one argument but I'm not sure? If anyone could help me out and link me a good wiki/resource about understanding documentation or explain it. I'll gladly appreciate it.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is not the spread operator.

Comment: @SergeK. Hm, you're right. What is this called in function signature then? In ruby, for example, both directions of the same thing are called "splat", defining (`def foo(*args)`) and calling (`foo(*args)`). I assumed here it's the same.

Comment: @SergeK.: also it appears that I misread the line. It's not an actual code. Oh well, I shall go back to what I know :)

Comment: @SergeK.: still, what is the name of the operator in `function foo(...args)`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes this comes from the documentation :) It is called [the rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), I looked it up on the documentation I didn't knew it.

Comment: Ty guys. I got it now. I knew it was a rest parameter but when I asked the question. I was mainly just wondering if there was some sort of wiki/resource online I could read that goes over what certain things in the documentation. For example. If you have something like [, callback]. That means it's an optional parameter. If you have something like "[color] | [size]". That means either one of them would work.